# Connecting to two databases

Tags: php, database

I have an application in which I want to authenticate a user from a first database & manage other activities from another database.
I have created two classes. An object of the classes is defined in a file:

```
$objdb1=new db1(),$objdb2=new db2();
```

But when I try to call `$objdb1->fn()`. It searches from the `$objdb2` & is showing table1 doesnot exists?

My first file database.php

```
class database
{
private $hostname;
private $database;
private $username;
private $password;
private $dblinkid;

function __construct()
{
    if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost')
    {
        $this->hostname = "localhost";
        $this->database = "aaaa";
        $this->username = "xxx";
        $this->password = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->hostname = "localhost";
        $this->database = "xxx";
        $this->username = "xxx";
        $this->password = "xxx";
    }
    $this->dblinkid = $this->connect();
}

       protected function connect()
{
    $linkid = mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password) or die("Could not Connect ".mysql_errno($linkid));
    mysql_select_db($this->database, $linkid) or die("Could not select database ".mysql_errno($linkid)) ;
    return $linkid;
}
```

Similarly second file

```
class database2
{
private $vhostname;
private $vdatabase;
private $vusername;
private $vpassword;
private $vdblinkid;

function __construct()
{
    if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost')
    {
        $this->vhostname = "xxx";
        $this->vdatabase = "bbbb";
        $this->vusername = "xxx";
        $this->vpassword = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->vhostname = "localhost";
        $this->vdatabase = "xxxx";
        $this->vusername = "xxxx";
        $this->vpassword = "xxxx";
    }
    $this->vdblinkid = $this->vconnect();
}

        protected function vconnect()
{
    $vlinkid = mysql_connect($this->vhostname, $this->vusername, $this->vpassword) or die("Could not Connect ".mysql_errno($vlinkid));
    mysql_select_db($this->vdatabase, $vlinkid) or die("Could not select database ".mysql_errno($vlinkid)) ;
    return $vlinkid;
}
```

Third file

```
$objdb1 = new database();
$objdb2 = new database2();
```

Can you help me on this?

Regards,

Pankaj

Comment: Not enough code. Show us how db1 et db2 are defined.

Comment: The advantages of classes is that you can have several instances that share the same functions but have different properties. In your case you could use just one class and create two instances with different properties (e.g. database connection information), so one for each database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your classes, it is difficult to help. If you are using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), I can guarantee you that you can create multiple instances connected to different databases without any problem. If you are using the `mysql_` family of functions you probably just forgot to set the `link_identifier` parameter (see [here](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)).

However, having a class `db1` and a class `db2` sounds like a code smell to me. You probably want to have two instances of the same class with different attributes.

Comment: The two classes look the same to me. Why are there two classes and not two instances of one class?

Comment: hi actually this code(database1.php) was being used in our earlier project and i started working on the new project using this file.
This new requirement came now , i can't change the code at this moment that's way i used the same approach with different classes.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call mysql_connect() or the equivalent mysqli functions, if a connection already exists using those same credentials it gets reused - so anything you do to modify the state of the connection, including changing database, charsets, or other mysql session variables affects "both" connections.

Since you are using the mysql_connect() function you have the option to force a new connection each time but this is not supported on all the extensions (IIRC mysqli and PDO don't alow for this).

However IMHO this is the wrong way to solve the problem. It just becomes messy trying to keep track of what's connected where.

The right way would be to specify the database in every query:

```
 SELECT stuff FROM aaaa.first f, aaaa.second s
 WHERE f.something=s.something;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your class does not pass the appropriate connection resource to the database functions. The second argument to e.g. [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is the connection resource. Simply store this resource in an instance variable on connection, and use it every time you do something with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be in checking if the SERVER_NAME is "localhost". Seems like you may be using the same connection strings in both classes. What is $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] resolving to?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the fourth parameter of `mysql_connect()`, which states that it shouldn't reuse existing connections:

```
$dbLink1 = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass, true);
mysql_select_db($db1, $dbLink1);

$dbLink2 = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass, true);
mysql_select_db($db2, $dbLink2);

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $dbLink1); // <-- Will work
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $dbLink2); // <-- Will fail, because table1 doesn't exists in $db2
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the fourth parameter as true to mysql_connect resolves the issue.

```
 $linkid = mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password,true) or die("Could not Connect ".mysql_errno($linkid));
```